# Red Hat Developer Studio 12 Project Explorer Not Responding

Tags: eclipse, jboss-developer-studio

I have Red Hat Developer Studio 12 and had imported a few Maven projects. However, when I restarted the application, I cannot open up neither Project Explorer nor Package Explorer.

In minimized view, when I click on any of their corresponding icons, RHDS stops responding and process hangs.

What I found out is, if I bring up Package Explorer from Window -> View -> Package Explorer, it loads and I can navigate through the modules. But if I click on the Project Explorer, it hangs.

As a matter of fact, if I try to remove the panel that houses both Explorer views, I realized that I can't open up Project Explorer at all on its own, since the application becomes unresponsive. I can open up Package Explorer just fine.

I even switched to Perspective Java from JBoss and the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the RHDS profile had been corrupted, so I had to reinstall the Eclipse again and was able to load dozens of Maven modules without the issue. I did not go ahead with deleting the profiles from the RHDS installed directories.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Red Hat Developer Studio are you using ?